# JavaScript Modules - SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word at exports.runInThisContext

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, export, cucumberjs

```
Benjamins-MacBook-Pro:Features Ben$ cucumber.js addItem.feature
/Users/Ben/WhatWeGrow.Web/public/Features/addItem.step.js:4
import * as a from "grocery-list";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:414:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cucumber/lib/cucumber/cli/support_code_loader.js:63:29
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.wrapper (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cucumber/lib/cucumber/cli/support_code_loader.js:62:15)
```

I'm using cucumberjs to do some BDD. I have a feature with two screnarios. They work when run in the terminal, when all of the js is in one file. I want to have the GroceryList class in a seperate file to make it cleaner.

I do the import like this:

```
'use strict';

import * as a from "grocery-list";
```

I do the export like this:

```
  module.exports = function () {

  class GroceryList {

    constructor() {
      this.list = {
        value: [],
        writable: false,
        enumerable: true
      };
    }

    add(item) {
      this.list.value.push(item);
    }

    getAll() {
      return this.list.value;
    }

    getItemIndex(value) {
      var index = this.list.value.length;
      while (--index > -1) {
        if (this.list.value[index] === value) {
          return index;
        }
      }
      return -1;
    }
  }
  }
```

What am I doing wrong to get this error? Google searches of the issue say things like:

> It looks like it can't find babel and babel-core. Do you have those on
>   your node_modules directory?

I have a lot of node_modules directories so not quite sure what to do. But I believe cucumberjs uses node.js. I just can't see where in the code it references node.js.

I updated to the latest version of node.js. Here is my terminal running my cucumber.js feature and the new error I am getting:

```
Benjamins-MacBook-Pro:Features Ben$ node -v
v4.2.3
Benjamins-MacBook-Pro:Features Ben$ node -v
v5.3.0
Benjamins-MacBook-Pro:Features Ben$ cucumber.js addItem.feature
/Users/Ben/WhatWeGrow.Web/public/Features/addItem.step.js:4
import * as a from "grocery-list";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:405:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cucumber/lib/cucumber/cli/support_code_loader.js:63:29
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.wrapper (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cucumber/lib/cucumber/cli/support_code_loader.js:62:15)
Benjamins-MacBook-Pro:Features Ben$
```

Here are my `node --v8-options` options for `--harmony`:

```
es_staging (enable all completed harmony features)
        type: bool  default: false
  --harmony (enable all completed harmony features)
        type: bool  default: false
  --harmony_shipping (enable all shipped harmony fetaures)
        type: bool  default: true
  --legacy_const (legacy semantics for const in sloppy mode)
        type: bool  default: true
  --harmony_modules (enable "harmony modules" (in progress))
        type: bool  default: false
  --harmony_regexps (enable "harmony regular expression extensions" (in progress))
        type: bool  default: false
  --harmony_proxies (enable "harmony proxies" (in progress))
        type: bool  default: false
  --harmony_sloppy_function (enable "harmony sloppy function block scoping" (in progress))
        type: bool  default: false
  --harmony_sloppy_let (enable "harmony let in sloppy mode" (in progress))
        type: bool  default: false
  --harmony_unicode_regexps (enable "harmony unicode regexps" (in progress))
        type: bool  default: false
  --harmony_reflect (enable "harmony Reflect API" (in progress))
        type: bool  default: false
  --harmony_destructuring (enable "harmony destructuring" (in progress))
        type: bool  default: false
  --harmony_default_parameters (enable "harmony default parameters" (in progress))
        type: bool  default: false
  --harmony_sharedarraybuffer (enable "harmony sharedarraybuffer" (in progress))
        type: bool  default: false
  --harmony_atomics (enable "harmony atomics" (in progress))
        type: bool  default: false
  --harmony_simd (enable "harmony simd" (in progress))
        type: bool  default: false
  --harmony_array_includes (enable "harmony Array.prototype.includes")
        type: bool  default: false
  --harmony_tostring (enable "harmony toString")
        type: bool  default: false
  --harmony_concat_spreadable (enable "harmony isConcatSpreadable")
        type: bool  default: false
  --harmony_rest_parameters (enable "harmony rest parameters")
        type: bool  default: false
  --harmony_sloppy (enable "harmony features in sloppy mode")
        type: bool  default: false
  --harmony_arrow_functions (enable "harmony arrow functions")
        type: bool  default: true
  --harmony_new_target (enable "harmony new.target")
        type: bool  default: true
  --harmony_object_observe (enable "harmony Object.observe")
        type: bool  default: true
  --harmony_spreadcalls (enable "harmony spread-calls")
        type: bool  default: true
  --harmony_spread_arrays (enable "harmony spread in array literals")
        type: bool  default: true
  --harmony_object (enable "harmony Object methods")
        type: bool  default: true
```

Comment: Make sure the version of Node you've got supports ES2015.

Comment: @Pointy I just upgraded my node.js and updated my question with the new error.

Comment: You may have to explicitly request ES2015 ("harmony") features. Do a `node --v8-options` and see what the default is for the `--harmony` option.

Comment: @Pointy just did and added the result to the question. I see --Harmony_modules is defaulted to false. How might I change that setting? Cheers.

Comment: Well I'm afraid I can't help; I've never used Cucumber or anything else like that, so I don't know what you would do to affect the way Node is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Node doesn't have support for EcmaScript Modules as yet.